# SnapSVG how do I add a fill attribute to this element

Tags: javascript, snap.svg

How do i set the fill attribute of the SVG file while loading the SVG file, before I append it to the paper?

```
Snap.load('svg/' + target, function (frag) {
    var group = frag.select('g');

    group.transform(Snap.format('translate({x},{y})', {
        x: this.x,
        y: this.y,
    }));

    /*
       CODE HERE
    */

    this.paper.append(group);
}, {
    paper: this.paper,
    x: this_x,
    y: y,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try something like below?

```
group.attr({fill: "#bada55"});
```

May be below link will give you more idea

http://snapsvg.io/start/